# Pass multiples arguments to a slot Qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slots, qt-connection

I'm using a Qt horizontal slider and I want to connect its valueChanged signal to a slot I defined. However I need to access a specific member inside this slot to modify a variable thanks to the int I set with the slider. Until now, my connect line has looked like this:

`connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setVariable(int)));`

Is it possible to pass more than one argument to my slot? What I'd like to do is something like:

`connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setVariable(int, pointerToMember*)));`

If not how can I proceed?

Comment: Where does the value of `pointerToMember*` come from?  If it's known at the time `connect` is called then you can use a capturing [`lambda`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-4) as the slot.

Comment: My pointer is defined in the same method from which I create this connect, a few lines before, so I guess I can try your suggestion

Comment: wich QT version are you using?

Comment: I'm working on Qt 6.2.1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, but you need to use new connect style, so you can pass lambda function

```
connect(slider, &QAbstractSlider::valueChanged, this, [=](int &new_value) { this->setVariable(new_value, ... );});
```

Edit:
This works only in Qt5 and above